# 500 internal server error on a single node

Tags: nodes, http-request

This just happend randomly today. I tried to access a page, but it keeps giving me a 500 internal server error http://www.austravel.com/holiday-destinations/australia

All the other pages are working fine. Any ideas why this may be?

Comment: Is there any error_log file in the root of the site?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Sorry for not posting this sooner.

Just to answer @AgA yes there is a **error_log file, I checked it and found the problem.**

For anyone wondering, it was just a large image file that was breaking the page. I deleted it from the page and it worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

Display PHP errors for that page or examine your Apache log file with errors enabled. Nobody can tell you what's misconfigured, or whatever typo you've made in your PHP ... log files can tell you though.

**EDIT:**

For further explanation on "errors" and specifically 500 error from Apache see:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8564259/php-5-3-troubleshooting-500-errors-debugging-parse-errors

> PHP will respond with a "500" when it encounters a Fatal error, such
>   as E_PARSE, E_ERROR and uncaught exceptions. 500 is the HTTP response
>   code for "Internal Server Error" - something unrecoverable happened
>   while processing the request.
>
> In your php.ini, on a development machine, you should set your
>   error_reporting level to (at least) E_NOTICE - preferably E_ALL - and
>   make sure display_errors is on. This will show you the error message
>   in the browser, including for "500" errors.
>
> You can also check your Apache error logs, the errors will be listed
>   there, as long as log_errors is enabled in php.ini. By default, this
>   will be at \logs\error.log.
>
> You can also control all this at run time with ini_set() and
>   error_reporting()

Comment: Thanks tenken. I've asked the IT team here to take a look into this but I'm also trying to find the php error logs, as I think this will be a key to what is happening. The server has been configured very differently so may take a while to figure out. If I find the issue, I'll post it here for anybody that may have the issue in the future.